# mod_rewrite / query_string

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, query-string

I get some basic results from a mysql database and list it on a page, on the page I've added the links with the variable user_id:

```
href=\"http://localhost/TESTING/template.php?user_id=$user_id\" >click here
```

On the template.php file I'll get the $user_id and display the relevant full data.

The thing is I don't want user_id=249 http://localhost/TESTING/template.php?**user_id=**249 to show in the url I'd like something like "http://localhost/TESTING/template.php/249".

I've been looking into this for a few days now with no success, is this possible? Or does the template file need the user_id=$user_id to be displayed in order to get the variable?

=====================

To update: I added the code

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /TESTING/

RewriteRule ^template.php/([0-9]+)(/)?$ template.php?user_id=$1 [L]

Changed the link variable to href="localhost/TESTING/template.php/{$user_id}" >click here

The re-write now works, but I'm not getting the variable with $user_id = $_GET["user_id"]; on the template.php page

I added the following to the template.php page to see whats being passed through the url:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
echo '<b>$_GET Variables</b><pre>';
var_dump( $_GET );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

and got the following response:

$_GET Variables

array(1) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(2) "21"
}

How to get the variable?

===========

To update now works! {$user_id} in the link not {user_id} - could of swore i tried both ways.

Comment: also let us know what server/set up i.e windows/unix

Answer (score 2):

Note that mod_rewrite only works on an Apache server.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /TESTING/

RewriteRule ^template.php/([0-9]+)(/)?$ template.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This looks like something I've been trying to get to work but this still shows the url as: http://localhost/TESTING/template.php?user_id=249

Comment: I'm running xampp btw and have checked if mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: I don't think you understand how mod_rewrite works. It doesn't rewrite the URLs you output, it only rewrites the URL requests it receives to another URL.

Comment: When you link to the page, don't use href="http://localhost/TESTING/template.php?user_id=$user_id" >click here.... Use: href="http://localhost/TESTING/template.php//{$user_id}" >click here

Comment: thanks radu, getting somewhere now, it displays the page with the new url but without any of the variables, so my mysql_query on the template page isn't finding the {user_id} variable. this is what i use: 
$user_id = $_GET["user_id"];

Comment: $user_id = $_GET["user_id"]; should work. But only if the url is valid, something like localhost/TESTING/template.php/234. I guess you are trying to get from a page to another one. On the first page, the $user_id should come from the database for instance, and it will be available on the second. Tell me if you want something else.

Comment: Yes the first page is a search results page with basic info, and the link is to dispay the full data of a particular result.

Comment: Well it should work. Make sure you don't have syntax errors, like using {user_id} instead of {$user_id}. If it still doesn't work, please provide some code.

Comment: Hi radu, I've posted an update on my question, if you've got the time to check it out and see what you make of it, I'd be grateful. :)

Comment: Forget that, now works like a charm! It was the {$user_id} I had {user_id}, as you said above. I could of swore i tried it a few times either way! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ok. You're welcome. If you need any more help, you know where to search. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be inpolite, but there are a lot of manuals in the interwebs, e.g.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

which explains, with examples, everything you need. What have you tried so far? So we can explain what's wrong.

Comment: Well, for example the post by radu is similar to what I've been trying but with no luck.